# How does the Simic Scientist background work?

Tags: dnd-5e, background

My DM asked me a question about the Simic Scientist background:

- How are you able to give people different animal and such parts, and how can I create monsters? I am wondering about the Simic Hybrid, and could I go further than what is listed? For example: Could some troll DNA be spliced into someone to give them regeneration? We got 2 troll corpses.

I am using the *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica* book since we only so D&D resources that is printed and are canon. Slight but not very powerful or gamebreaking homebrew

Comment: The version of Simic scientist I see in *Guildmaster’s Guide to Ravnica* doesn’t have any particular ability to edit DNA at all; the background just gives some research skills (where to find knowledge), and adds some spells to your spell list(s). Which Simic scientist background gives you an ability to edit DNA?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of the fluff in the background of [this UA article](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_RavnicaRaces.pdf)? That seems like something you should mention if it is the case.

Comment: Yes i was talking about the simic hybrid and was wondering if i could add other things other then what id listed

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clearly reflect what material you are using and what your question is.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. It's still not clear to me what part of your post is your DM's question, and which is yours - the pronouns seem to switch halfway through the sentence. (The last sentence is also not clearly phrased, specifically: "since we only so D&D resources that is printed and are canon. Slight but not very powerful or gamebreaking homebrew".)